# Query regarding iOS certificate renewal

Tags: ios, certificate, app-store

I have an app in appstore, whose certificate is about to expire in 20 days. So i created new distribution certificate & new provisioning profile(used same previous appid) > then recreated build & submitted to Appstore.  My queries in here is;
Is above process is the proper way of doing it.

1) I haven't revoked old certificate, it's still in account. Do I need to do anything to it or just leave it alone?

2) what if users didn't update my latest build (with new certificate) from appstore & instead try to stay with old build that got certificate about to expire shortly? In such cases, what'll happen to app, once cert is expired?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: FYI - when you wish to reply to someone, precede their username with the @ sign.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There was no reason at all to submit a new build to the App Store - at least due to the certificate. An expired certificate only affects your ability to use provisioning profiles. Existing apps are not affected at all.

Users that don't update will not be affected.

Feel free to delete any old certificates. Use the new one to create new provisioning profiles.

Comment: I do have some new features in this release. So I did an updated build

Comment: OK, that's fine. That's why I specifically said there was no reason just due to the certificate. The rest applies.

Comment: Thanks @rmaddy, your comments really helps me in getting clarified on this issue